# Join operation equivalent of nested for loop for pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, outer-join

I have below tables -

| Audit ID | Customer ID | Budget | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 100 | 2023-05-01 07:40:56 |
| 2 | 456 | 70 | 2023-05-01 12:20:50 |
| 3 | 456 | 70 | 2023-05-01 17:30:50 |

| Audit ID | Product ID | Price | TimeStamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 5556 | 5 | 2023-05-01 06:40:56 |
| 6 | 5556 | 90 | 2023-05-01 06:40:56 |
| 7 | 7778 | 20 | 2023-05-01 12:20:50 |
| 9 | 7987 | 60 | 2023-05-01 05:50:00 |
| 10 | 7987 | 50 | 2023-05-04 05:50:00 |

| Customer ID | Product ID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 5556 |
| 123 | 7987 |
| 456 | 7778 |
| 456 | 7987 |

Problem statement - Find count where customer budget is more than product price (pick latest product price before customer budget timestamp) and also the max delta between customer budget and product price.

Basically i need query equivalent of below python code for PySpark , i ran below code on pandas and it worked fine for small dataset but for large data set pandas is not able to process it. I came across PySpark and read that its faster but it seems we cannot write nested loop in pyspark.

```
count_intances_budget_more_than_price = 0;
map_customer_id_max_delta = {}
processed_product_for_customer = new set()

for cusomter_row in customer_dataset:
  max_delta = 0
  if customer_id in map_customer_id_max_delta:
      max_delta = map_customer_id_max_delta.get(customer_id)
  for product_row in product_dataset:
    if product_id in map_customer_id_product_id[customer_id]:
      if product_id not in processed_product_for_customer:
        processed_product_for_customer.add(product_id)
        if product_timestamp < customer_timestamp and product_price < customer_budget:
          count_intances_budget_more_than_price +=1
          max_delta = max(max_delta,customer_budget - product_price )
  map_customer_id_max_delta[customer_id] = max_delta 
  processed_product_for_customer.clear()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to join the 3 tables and aggregate on customer-id and count the number of matched products and calculate the max difference for each customer

Input:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

customerProductDf = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(123, 5556),
     (123, 7987),
     (456, 7778),
     (456, 7987)],
     StructType([
        StructField("CustomerId", IntegerType(), True), 
        StructField("ProductId", IntegerType(), True)
    ]))
customersDf = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(123, 100, datetime.strptime('2023-05-01 07:40:56', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
     (456, 70, datetime.strptime('2023-05-01 12:20:50', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
     (456, 70, datetime.strptime('2023-05-01 17:30:50', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))],
     StructType([
        StructField("CustomerId", IntegerType(), True), 
        StructField("Budget", IntegerType(), True), 
        StructField("TimeStamp", TimestampType(), True)
    ]))
productsDf = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(5556, 5, datetime.strptime('2023-05-01 06:40:56', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
     (5556, 90, datetime.strptime('2023-05-01 05:40:56', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
     (7778, 20, datetime.strptime('2023-05-01 12:20:50', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
     (7987, 60, datetime.strptime('2023-05-01 05:50:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')),
     (7987, 50, datetime.strptime('2023-05-04 05:50:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))],
     StructType([
        StructField("ProductId", IntegerType(), True), 
        StructField("Price", IntegerType(), True), 
        StructField("TimeStamp", TimestampType(), True)
    ]))
```

Calculations:

```py
window = Window.partitionBy(customersDf.CustomerId, productsDf.ProductId).orderBy(productsDf.TimeStamp)
customerVsDeltaDf = customerProductDf \
        .join(customersDf, 'CustomerId') \
        .join(productsDf, 'ProductId') \
        .filter((customersDf.TimeStamp > productsDf.TimeStamp) & (customersDf.Budget > productsDf.Price)) \
        .withColumn("LatestPrice", F.last(productsDf.Price).over(window)) \
        .drop(productsDf.Price) \
        .distinct() \ # Drop any duplicates to not affect the count
        .groupBy(customersDf.CustomerId) \
        .agg( \
            F.count(productsDf.ProductId).alias('Count'), \
            F.max(customersDf.Budget - F.col('LatestPrice')).alias('MaxPriceDiff') \
        )
```

Result:

```
>>> customerVsDeltaDf.show()
+----------+-----+------------+                                                    
|CustomerId|Count|MaxPriceDiff|
+----------+-----+------------+
|       456|    3|          50|
|       123|    2|          95|
+----------+-----+------------+

>>> customerVsDeltaDf.agg(F.sum('Count').alias("TotalCount")).show()
+----------+
|TotalCount|
+----------+
|         5|
+----------+
```

Comment: thank you. There is 1 more condition , i have updated the pseudo code.  How to make sure that only latest record of product price is updated

Comment: In this case you need to use the `Window` function to select the latest product relative to each customer. I have updated the answer

Comment: I have changed the example input of product `5556` so it can show the recency difference